# Form action as controller method?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I'm trying to fix a form that was created using a twig template. The form was not working because there was no action, nor was the form created using `FormStateInterface`. It's just a block that is rendering a template.

In this module there is a controller and in this controller a method that handles the form submission using `\Drupal::request()->request->all()` which should be the same as using `$_POST['']`, correct?

Could I not just do something like this:

`<form method="POST" action="/route/to/controller/method">`

if I'm wanting to use a custom form template?

I would really just like to know if this is an acceptable practice in the Drupal universe.

Comment: There are so, so many reasons to use the API over manually creating HTML for forms - automatic CSRF protection, ability for other modules to intuitively alter what you've provided/changed, easy and pluggable validation/submission, a myriad of elements already available with sensible and useful properties, to name just a few. Yes, you can use plain HTML and plain PHP if you want to, it's your dime after all. But if you do, one would have to ask: why are you using a framework in the first place?

Comment: You should not be creating HTML forms ad-hoc in Twig templates or otherwise, it simply won't play well when using Drupal. Of course, it is _possible_, if you want to read PHP superglobals and all that, but you will spend 10x the time instead of just using the Form API and different services. If this were a Form API generated form, all you would need to do is add in the submit function a `$form_state->setRedirect('route...');`. But since its a vanilla HTML form, Drupal has no idea it even exists. Custom form templates are secondary.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So using FormStateInterface is the standard way to create all forms in Drupal. That is all that I was wanting to know.I would give some upvotes, but I don't have the rep.

Comment: You’d want to extend FormBase. Check the docs for examples on how to start.